# How to crop image in a circle shape in Titanium?

Tags: image, titanium, appcelerator, shapes, geometry

You can crop an image by setting it to the background of a label and then setting the label to the size you want, but is there a way to crop it in a circle shape?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `borderRadius` to half of the images width/height will give you a circle shaped image.

```
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image        : '/images/myImage.png',
    width        : 60,
    height       : 60,
    borderRadius : 30
});
win.add(imageView);
```

For cropping images, [imageAsCropped](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob-method-imageAsCropped) is also quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution that use titanium ui. Without corners to be pixelated (Android).

```
<View id="userFaceContainer">                                       
     <ImageView id="avatar" />                    
     <View id="userFaceInnerBorder" />
</View>
```

and styles

```
"#avatar": {
   width: 90,
   height: 90
}

"#userFaceContainer": {
    width: 90,
    height: 90,
    center: {
       x:"50%", 
       y:"50%"
    },
    borderRadius: 45,
    borderColor: "#669dd3",
    borderWidth:2
}

"#userFaceInnerBorder": {
    width: 88,
    height: 88,
    borderRadius: 44,
    borderColor: "#669dd3",
    borderWidth:2,
    opacity: 0.7
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve an oval/circle shape with percent values instead of absolute?